# Bad encrypt with NextJS

Tags: python, node.js, next.js, cryptography

I have a client with NextJS and an API with Python. I have tried to encrypt information with the client and decrypt it with the API.
I have a script with NodeJS to test the encryption, and then I paste the encrypted data in Postman to test the API.

This is the code with NodeJS in NextJS.
I send to the API a base64 string of the encrypted data.

```
const publicKey = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

const encryptedData = crypto.publicEncrypt({
    key: Buffer.from(publicKey, 'utf-8'),
    padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING,
    oaepHash: 'sha256'
}, Buffer.from(data));

const encryptedDataBase64 = encryptedData.toString('base64');
return encryptedDataBase64
```

With Python, I get the base64 string and then decrypt the data.

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding

encrypted_data = base64.b64decode(b64data)

with open('./secure/private_key.pem', 'rb') as key_file:
    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        key_file.read(),
        password=None,
        backend=default_backend()
    )

decrypted_data_bytes = private_key.decrypt(
    encrypted_data,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        label=None
    )
)

decrypted_data = decrypted_data_bytes.decode('utf-8')

return decrypted_data
```

I've tried encrypting the data with:

- NextJS, and then sending the data through Postman
- NodeJS, and then sending the data through Postman
- NodeJS, then pasting the data in NextJS, then making a request to the API.

None of these decrypt in the API properly. The problem is when the data is encrypted in NextJS.

Comment: I don't think the problem is related to NextJS. NextJS serves as the front end of your code and allows users to have access to the API. Any data you encrypt in NextJS uses a library from NodeJS to encrypt it.
Unless you are using two different libraries, one in NextJS and one in your separate Node application, the front end shouldn't matter.

Comment: Could you post the full function from the first code block? It seems to return a string based on the input variable `data`, and it would be useful to see the full function in order to figure out how to decrypt the returned data.

Comment: For the failure case, have you checked whether `encryptedDataBase64` on the NextJS side and `b64data` on the Python side are *exactly* equal (to rule out data corruption)? Are the private and public keys associated, i.e. do they belong to the *same* key pair?